# Unfortunately HelloWorld Stopped (My app stopped on emulator: Unfortunately )

Tags: java, android

I am completely a beginner android developer but a good Java J2SE Developer. I just want to know that while I am working on first Android app: after compiling it and having no errors facing problems running it in an emulator!
my code for java class is:
package com.example.helloworld;

```
 import android.os.Bundle;
 import android.app.Activity;
 import android.view.Menu;
 import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

//Variables Declaration
private Button one;
private Button two;
private Button three;
private Button four;
private Button five;
private Button six;
private Button seven;
private Button eight;
private Button nine;
private Button plus;
private Button minus;
private Button divide;
private Button multiply;
private Button zero;
private Button dot;
private Button equal;
private Button clr;
//End of Variables Declaration

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    addListenerOnButton();



}

public void addListenerOnButton(){
    one=(Button) this.findViewById(R.id.button1);
    two=(Button) this.findViewById(R.id.button2);
    three=(Button) this.findViewById(R.id.button3);
    four=(Button) this.findViewById(R.id.button4);
    five=(Button) this.findViewById(R.id.button5);
    six=(Button) this.findViewById(R.id.button6);
    seven=(Button) this.findViewById(R.id.button7);
    eight=(Button) this.findViewById(R.id.button8);
    nine=(Button) this.findViewById(R.id.button9);
    zero=(Button) this. findViewById(R.id.button14);
    dot=(Button) this.findViewById(R.id.button15);
    plus=(Button) this.findViewById(R.id.button13);
    equal=(Button) this.findViewById(R.id.button16);
    clr=(Button) this.findViewById(R.id.button17);
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}


 }
```

the .xml is:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/rel"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@style/AppBaseTheme"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/lay"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/numf2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="numberDecimal" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/opf"
        android:layout_width="290dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="numberDecimal|text" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/numf1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="26dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="numberDecimal" >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>
</LinearLayout>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button1"
    android:text="2"
     />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button3"
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button2"
    android:text="3"
     />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button4"
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button1"
    android:text="4" 
    />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button5"
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/button4"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button4"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/button3"
    android:text="5"
     />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button6"
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/button5"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button5"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button3"
    android:text="6"
     />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button7"
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/button4"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button4"
    android:text="7" 
    />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button8"
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/button5"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button5"
    android:text="8"
     />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button9"
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/button6"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button6"
    android:text="9"
     />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button10"
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/button9"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button6"
    android:text="Button" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button11"
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/button10"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/button6"
    android:text="Button" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button12"
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button11"
    android:layout_below="@+id/button11"
    android:text="Button" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button13"
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button12"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/button12"
    android:text="+" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/button13"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/lay"
    android:text="1" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button14"
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/button13"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button13"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/button2"
    android:text="0" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button15"
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button3"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/button3"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/button13"
    android:text="dot" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button16"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/button13"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button13"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/lay"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button12"
    android:text="=" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button17"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button16"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/lay"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/button10"
    android:text="CLR" />

 </RelativeLayout>
```

please help me I have searched a lot but failed to find any solution my app does't start at all and unfortunately it stopped. Thanks in advance

Comment: please have a look at the logcat error output first, post it here if possible.

Comment: I am new to Android Development tell me how can I post the Log? Please!

Comment: in the menu bar of eclipse Window>>show view>>LogCat

Comment: [2013-05-06 17:13:33 - DeviceMonitor] Sending Tracking request failed!

THE ERROR!!!

Comment: Did you add the activity to your AndroidManifest.xml file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tested your code (*the XML as well as the Java*) in a quick test project. It crashes all right. Apparently, the layout does not like `android:background` attribute set in it.

Removing this line from the parent RelativeLayout will fix it:

```
android:background="@style/AppBaseTheme"
```

Testing on my device:

[image]

The final parent `RelativeLayout` will look this this:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/rel"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    ....

    ....

</RelativeLayout>
```

As to why it does not like that attribute is because it maps to a style in the `styles.xml` called: `AppBaseTheme`. If you have created the project using the *Android Application Project* wizard, as I did, I have noticed it creates a *blank* styles.xml with just this in it:

```
<resources>

    <!--
        Base application theme, dependent on API level. This theme is replaced
        by AppBaseTheme from res/values-vXX/styles.xml on newer devices.
    -->
    <style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="android:Theme.Light">
        <!--
            Theme customizations available in newer API levels can go in
            res/values-vXX/styles.xml, while customizations related to
            backward-compatibility can go here.
        -->
    </style>

    <!-- Application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
        <!-- All customizations that are NOT specific to a particular API-level can go here. -->
    </style>

</resources>
```

Naturally, the attribute `android:background="@style/AppBaseTheme"` does not have the necessary  that will supply the `RelativeLayout` with a resource that is compatible with the `android:background` attribute.

Comment: so I have to remove this line of code "android:background="@style/AppBaseTheme" from my .xml?

Comment: @JunaidHassan: Correct. From the parent `RelativeLayout` as shown in the code. (_I forgot to remove it from the answer by mistake_). See how it looks now.

Comment: lols lemme tell you one more problem this Eclipse IDE sucks a lot I bet sure NetBeans well serves Developers for it User Friendly Behavior. Now my Eclipse stops working as well as the emulator is also not showing even the home screen lols it hangs a for a long time

Comment: @JunaidHassanL Matter of opinion really. ;-) When I started with Android development over 2 years ago, NetBeans and IntelliJ were not the easiest of connect to the Android ADT. Now I am used to Eclipse. :-)

Comment: can you please tell me why it become unresponsive now I mean it is now only showing the splash screen and i have been waiting for the home screen to come up since last 30 minuts

Comment: @JunaidHassan: Can't say why buddy. :-( Perhaps a computer restart should fix it.

Comment: thanks for your kind help i have reinstalled my adt and all! fixed my error and +1 for your kind time for me

Comment: @JunaidHassan: You had to reinstall the ADT? Ouch! Well, I am glad to have been of help. Welcome and good luck with Android devlopment buddy. :-)